# Remove CarrierWave file from associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

What is the proper way to remove an attachment through an associated model?

I have a Profile.rb model that `has_one` Will.rb model. The will is edited through the same form as the profile. I'm able to attach a file using my `:will_attachment` field but trying to use the `:remove_will_attachment` checkbox doesn't work.

The Params structure is as follows:

```
"portfolio" =>
 {"will_attributes" =>
    {"remove_will_attachment"
    }
  }
```

I do have `:will_attachment` and `:remove_will_attachment` in the permitted params method.

I'm currently having to remove the attachment by checking for `remove_will_attachment == "1"` in the params and manually calling `@portfolio.will.remove_will_attachment!` but it seems there should be a smoother way to do this.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug in CarrierWave that is **solved on the master branch**. For a reason it does not remove the uploaded file if only the `remove_#{column}` attribute accessor is set.

In CarrierWave 0.10, this will not work

```
"portfolio" =>
 {"will_attributes" =>
    {"remove_will_attachment" => true
    }
 }
```

This will

```
"portfolio" =>
 {"will_attributes" =>
    {"remove_will_attachment" => true,
     "another_attribute" => "CHANGED VALUE"
    }
 }
```